# Exclude directories for MVC Role Provider using web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I have a role provider that is used for most of my web sites. I need to exclude several directories from attempting to use the role providers. Can this be configured in the web.config? If so, how?

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="RoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="RoleProvider" type="MyFramework.Mvc.Common.RoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: What do you mean that “Exclude directories”? restrict users to access, is that correct? Please consider to below code segments.

Comment: <location path="myfolder">
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
         <!--for authentication, we should enable either windows authentication or form authentication in IIS authentication module.-->
            <add accessType="Allow" roles="Administrators" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
</location>